# Alerts stop working in Javascript after added getElementById statements

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to debug the javascript in the HTML (showModalDialog) bound to a Google spreadsheet. Neither Logger.log nor console.log show up anywhere but most of the time alerts can be seen. I have pared my code down to find out which instructions stop the alerts from being displayed. Why? When I uncomment the two getElementById, the alerts are no longer displayed.

```
      document.getElementById('errMsg').innerHTML = 'All fields are STILL required';  // output field
      document.getElementById("errMsg").style.font-weight = "normal";
```

If I comment them out the alerts appear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Select Color Change</title>
    <!--This is a comment. -->
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <style>

      #subBut,
      #clrBut,
      #text_before {
        display: block;             /* show */
        visibility: visible;
      }
      
      .whtBkgrd {
        background-color: WHITE;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }
      
      .coloredBkgrd{
        background-color: #e6f8fa;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--This is a comment. -->
    <span id='text_before'>
      You have gone to
      <select class='select' name='Q1' id='q1'
        onchange='this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className'>
      <option class='coloredBkgrd' value='0' selected='selected'>Select</option>
      <option class='whtBkgrd' value='a'>a</option>
      <option class='whtBkgrd' value='an'>an</option>
      <option class='whtBkgrd' value='the'>the</option>
      <option class='whtBkgrd' value='nothing '>(nothing) </option>
      </select> doctor for an illness.
    </span> 
 
    <span class='buttons'>
      <span>
        <button type='submit' id='subBut' value='submit' >SUBMIT</button>
        <button type='button' id='clrBut' value='clear' >RESET</button>
      </span>
    </span>
    <hr />
    
    <span>
        <!-- <p></p> -->
      <span id='errMsg' aria-live='polite' >
        Please make all selections.
      </span>
    </span>
    
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        // - - - - - - - -  LISTENERS - - - - - - - -
    document.getElementById('subBut').addEventListener('click', 
      function(event)      {
        alert('Begin submit addEventListener');
//        debugger;
        cSideValidate();
        // event.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
      }
    );

    document.getElementById('clrBut').addEventListener('click', 
      function(event)    {
        alert('Begin clear addEventListener');
//        debugger;
      //    the listener has to be separate from the actual function!
        clearReset();
      }
    );
    
    document.getElementById('ansrBut').addEventListener('click', 
      function(event)    {
        alert('Begin ansrBut addEventListener');
//        debugger;
      //    the listener has to be separate from the actual function!
        showAnswers();
      }
    );


    // - - - - - - - -  FUNCTIONS - - - - - - - -
    function cSideValidate() {
      alert('in cSideValidate');
     document.getElementById('errMsg').innerHTML = 
       'Still working - please wait for final message';
    }
    
    function clearReset() {    
      alert('in clearReset()');
       
      //  document.getElementById('errMsg').innerHTML = 'All fields are STILL required';  // output field
      //  document.getElementById("errMsg").style.font-weight = "normal"; 

      document.getElementById('q1').selectedIndex = 0;
      document.getElementById('q1').style.backgroundColor = '#e6f8fa';
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is much more complicated but I have isolated this glitch?!?!? I really need a way to debug Javascript in HTML attached to Google docs.

Code to run the HTML:

```
function launchMinHtml() {

  var html = HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('minHtml') 
    .evaluate();
  
//  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('about to show html');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, ' ');
}
```

the Spreadsheet menu in the onLoad function:

```
function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()   // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Dialog')
      .addItem('Open Form 1', 'openForm1')
      .addItem('Minimun HTML', 'launchMinHtml')
      .addItem('Select Color Change', 'launchSelectColorChg')
      .addItem('Dynamic Select', 'launchDynamicSelect')
      .addToUi();

}
```

Comment: Identifiers in JavaScript can't contain dashes (it will be seen as a subtraction). Use `style.fontWeight`.

Comment: Client side errors will not be shown of the Google Apps Script logger, project execution page or Stack Driver by default, but they might me logged in the web browser console.

Comment: The server side code that opens the modal dialog is missing.

Comment: @Ivar errMsg does not contain a dash.

Comment: @Rubén said "but they might be logged in the web browser console." when you launch the HTML from the menu you cannot (as far as I know) see the Chrome console

Comment: Just open the Chrome DevTools i.e. by pressing F12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand upon the above comments, you look like you've a syntax error in your code, which stops it executing. Checking your web console in your browser, it  -should reference that line, where it halts. Your second line should look like this:

```
  document.getElementById("errMsg").style.fontWeight = "normal";
```

Comment: thanks for the explicit help. I need to learn to go more slowly and add my code line by line as there is not insight (that I know about) into javascript in this circumstance

Comment: Easy done sir, it's a long road but worth it! I have been there, tearing my hair out and will be again I'm sure :) No problem.